# css bug - div with image gallery cut only for iphones 6/7/8 - flex and grid

Tags: css, iphone

I spent a load of times to resolve a css problem which is only on iphones without success.
To use the web inspector code and see what happens on the iphone safari, I must have a mac and I don´t have this computer so I´m coding blindly.

My CSS works for most of the screens and androids, I go this result (that I expect)

[image]

But on iphone 8, I got this :

[image]

For some reasons, photos are bigger, it´s not organized with two columns and `.pr-section-inner-block` with orange border does not match with its contents and cut the gallery. Maybe its behaviour is to get the same height than the previous `.pr-section-inner-block` because of flex.

**CSS**

```
pr-section-inner{
    padding: 75px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.pr-section-inner .pr-section-inner-block{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)  {
    .pr-section-inner{
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
    }

    .pr-section-inner .pr-section-inner-block{
        border: 2px solid orange;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
    }

    .pr-section-inner .pr-section-inner-block .pr-section-inner-block-content{
        border: 2px solid red;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
    }
}
```

Someone has got an idea to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
It seems that Safari for iphones interprates `display: flex;` even if the behaviour is wrong. Normally it should only interprate `display: -webkit-box;` so I switched these 2 rules.

```
.h4a-pr-section-inner{
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box; /* After display :flex; */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}
```